# Setting up the SharePoint+Silverlight Blueprint Colleague Viewer Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, silverlight-2.0, web-parts, blueprint

I'm trying to get the Silverlight Colleague Viewer webpart to work on my test server. The silverlight player renders the Viewer but it fails when it attempts to access the WCF service. The error below is caught by IE 8.

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR >1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR >3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
>   Timestamp: Tue, 14 Apr 2009 21:45:18 UTC
>
> Message: Unhandled Error in
>   Silverlight 2 Application An exception
>   occurred during the operation, making
>   the result invalid.  Check
>   InnerException for exception details. 
>   at
>   System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
>   at
>   SL.XAML.ColleagueViewer.Proxies.GetUserProfileInfoCompletedEventArgs.get_Result()
>   at
>   SL.XAML.ColleagueViewer.Page.proxy_GetUserProfileInfoCompleted(Object
>   sender,
>   GetUserProfileInfoCompletedEventArgs
>   e)    at
>   SL.XAML.ColleagueViewer.Proxies.SocialNetworkingClient.OnGetUserProfileInfoCompleted(Object
>   state) Line: 1 Char: 1 Code: 0 URI:
>   http://mytestsite/_layouts/1033/init.js?rev=ck%2BHdHQ8ABQHif7kr%2Bj7iQ%3D%3D

I have copied all of the necessary modification for silverlight to my web.config and run the install.bat file on my server.

Anyone have any thoughts. If more details are needed please comment and I will try to provide them.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure everything is in order in your silverlight install, there are more steps to the blue print than just modifying the web.config, specifically:

Install of WSS SP1 and/or MOSS SP1. Downloading and installing the silverlight SDK and copying appropriate files to your GAC. Installing .net 3.5 (system.web.extensions), adding the MIME type, etc.

Make sure you have done all of this, check out: http://www.u2u.info/Blogs/Patrick/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?Name=Silverlight%20BluePrint

That said, I do not believe this is an install of Silverlight issue. (At least from the errors), check the install/reqs of the webpart again, there may be services it is dependent on that it does not have access to/are installed.

Comment: I have tried all of the things that you mentioned above without any success. I have since built a new wcf service from scratch and implemented it without problem. I'm using Colleague Viewer Webpart project as my template and so far no problems. If my error starts replicating in my new project I will post up what I discover from that.